# What are common mistakes made by Japanese kombini employees speaking "manual keigo" (バイト敬語)

Tags: keigo, business-japanese

Mainly inspired by [this question on what seems to be the misuse of a standard idiom by a Japanese employee](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/798/usage-of-chdo/), I was reminded of being told about バイト敬{けい}語{ご} ("manual keigo") in the past: a slightly dumbed-down sonkeigo crash course handed to new kombini recruits, that covers the basics but often results in widespread misuse of proper keigo forms at the hands of young Japanese unused to this level of speech.

I know there were a couple very specific examples of classic mistakes (generally: confusions between sonkeigo and kenjôgo). [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E6%95%AC%E8%AA%9E) ([en](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_keigo)) lists a few disputed forms (「おつぎのお客{きゃく}様{さま}」,「〜になります」...) present in the manuals themselves...

I'd be interested to hear if anybody has other examples of egregious misuse and why they are not correct.

Comment: I don't approve of the word "mistake" in the heading here. If you have the kind of job where you have to follow the manual or you get fired, it is not a "mistake" to do what the manual says, even if the manual happens to include language that others may find objectionable (or, more likely, pretend to find objectionable as an oblique claim of social or intellectual superiority over their minimum-wage-earning interlocutor).

Comment: @Matt: point taken. And to a larger extent, one could criticise the ultra-prescrivist approach reflected in the view held by purists regarding "manual keigo" (especially when said "improper" forms have probably become the standard). That being said, "mistakes" seemed the easiest way to carry the meaning across in a title. If you have better suggestion, I'm open to updates :-)

Comment: How about something like "What distinctive features of 'manual keigo'/バイト敬語 are considered incorrect by more traditional keigo style manuals?" That allows for the reality that the idea of "incorrectness" is probably the majority view without granting it the status of objective fact. (That said, the title doesn't bother me all that much -- I do understand the spirit it was intended in. I just wanted to explicitly put the prescriptivist POV on record too.)

Comment: Nihongo no Shiranai Nihongo covers this in episode 2: http://youtu.be/bjEhZOK80q0?t=4m32s

Comment: As a foreigner learning Japanese, I may as well learn the "incorrect" (descriptivist) keigo, and not bother learning the "correct" (prescriptivist) keigo, unless I plan to be speaking this kind of keigo myself.

Answer (score 5):

Using ～から like １万円**から**お預かりします, which seems to be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I don't even know how that would make sense...

Comment: @YOU: Not sure if you mean that 「〜１万円から」is or isn't grammatically correct...? Wikipedia article I linked seems to say the form is only incorrect when paired with 預かりします, but makes good sense (and probably is the root of the confusion) when used on its own (to mean "giving back change from ~")...

Comment: @Dave, I supposed to mean that one, but I wasn't sure there is another usage, so I left it out. May be I should put it.

Comment: @YOU: What is the correct keigo for this?

Comment: @Nicolas, In my opinion, just skip から, but I am not 100% sure, because I heard it from somewhere else that I don't remember, not internet I think, so I don't have definite source for that. You may ask it on another question, so somebody could find out some references.

Comment: **から** is grammatically incorrect here.  It should be **を**.  It's supposed to be ＜人＞から＜もの＞を預かる.  So the correct statement should be お客様から一万円をお預かりします.

Comment: Related: http://i.imgur.com/HPblU.jpg

Comment: Yeah. They are taking 10000Y FROM ME, not from the bill. That's why it's a famous example of bad keigo. When that happens to me, I correct them: "いいえ、「お客さんから1万円をおあずかりします」って言いたかったんですね？!"

Comment: While I'd say this has become such a common idiom that it is no longer considered incorrect IMO. The 「から」 has the same effect as "なります". It's a softner. I don't think ppl are confusing the subject. But that's my theory :p

Comment: @phirru - I have that book!

Comment: @makdad: Is the book "nihonjin no shiranai nihongo"? I heard about it this weekend, and I've seen the tv series version discuss manual keigo.

Comment: Isn't the implication that the bill is being extracted from your 10000yen? Doesn't seem illogical.

Answer (score 4):

Another one that is frequently brought up is 「ご注文は以上でよろしかったでしょうか？」, where the "correct" form is 「ご注文は以上でよろしいでしょうか？」.

Adding 「～のほう」 is also very common (e.g. 「お車のほうは大丈夫でしたか？」).

These are all attempts to soften the language (i.e. to be more polite) (at least according to my theory!). The first example uses past tense, the second uses an indirection by talking about the "direction where the car is" rather than just directly mentioning the car itself.

IMO it's always tough to define what is "incorrect" and "correct". After all, even when you look at the Japanese language just 30 years ago, it's quite different from how it's spoken now. Not to mention how it changed since the Meiji-era etc. :p

Personally I find these indirections annoying but perhaps that's just how the language is evolving. Right now though, it is true that many consider these 敬語 to be wrong. Especially older ppl.

Answer (score 0):

> お釣りは、◯◯円になります。

If someone said this, I'd reply with

> おおすごい! 本当に◯◯円になったよ。手品か?!
>   *Wowie! It really became xx yen. Is it a magic trick?!*

Comment: why? 「になります」to me is in that situation a polite 「です」.  Did I miss something?

Comment: This is also not really wrong. なります is "softer" than です. It is true that some consider this as wrong, but it's very very commonly used.

Comment: This is perfectly correct. It can be better translated as "The change turns out to be __ yen", not "became".

Comment: @Axioplase If you are talking about the honorific form `お...になる`, then first of all, that applies to verbs only, and if it were possible, that means you are showing respect to the coins.

Comment: I don't even think of any honorific form when I hear "お釣り".  All I hear is "your change amounts to ○○," politely.

Comment: I think you have coined (no pun intended) an Oyaji-gag rather than pointed out a grammatical error.

Comment: @StuartWoodward Rather than coining it, I may have heard it somewhere and mistook it as a popular grammatical error. I still am trying to recall the other incorrect 敬語 usage.

Comment: The problem is なる isn't the polite form of である, でござる is. It should be ◯◯円でございます。Not that I'm at all qualified to say that (technically I'm still in my first year of Japanese)